# Concurrent reads on a file in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a file onto which I have written some data. Say 8 bytes of data
Now using my python script, I want to read the first four bytes using one thread and the next 4 bytes using another thread while the first thread is still running or suspended. 
How can I do this using python? i.e
1) Read first 4 bytes using thread1 from file1
2) while thread1 running or suspended, read next 4 bytes from file1 using thread2

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Wouldn't it be easier to have only one thread read from the file and then hand off the data to workers to process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run two threads and open and read file separately in both threads, you can use `seek` to jump to specific positions

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class MyFileWrapper:

    def __init__(self, filePath, start, stop):
        self.filePath = filePath
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def getData(self):
        with open(self.filePath, 'r') as f:
            f.seek(self.start)
            data = f.read(self.stop - self.start)
            print data

def worker(q):
    myFileWrapper = q.get()
    myFileWrapper.getData()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    work_queue = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue,))
    p2.start()

    work_queue.put(MyFileWrapper('C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\pytest.txt', 0, 4))
    work_queue.put(MyFileWrapper('C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\pytest.txt', 4, 8))

    work_queue.close()
    work_queue.join_thread()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```